# How to Return last occurrence of value in Array using VB6

Tags: arrays, vb6

Hi need to return the index of the last occurrence of a value in an array. 
I tried this but it won't work. What am I doing wrong?

NOT THE LAST INDEX.. I am looking for the last index of a specific value contained within an array. in this case, it should return 3 which would be the last index of the value "this"

in a zero based array this should return 3

```
  Dim ary() As Variant
  Dim  stg as string
  stg = "this,one,is,this,going,to,be,fun"
  ary = Split(stg, ",")

  MsgBox (ary.LastIndexOf(ary, "this"))
```

Comment: Try the `UBound()` function.  You can find it by Reading That Fine Manual.

Comment: -_-  .. ..   Hi Bob, you understand I am NOT looking for the last index, but the last index of a specific value contained within the array right?

Comment: Sorry, I completely misread your intent.  But if you want that you must enumerate the elements and test until you find your target.  You could also look at `Filter()` but I doubt it does what you want either.

Comment: I am thinking I can Join my array into a Comma separated string and then find last value using instr .. playing with it now. Just can't figure out how to count values so my new function can return index of array

Comment: i have a feeling you are mixing vb6 with .NET functions. I don't think LastIndexOf belongs to the array in classic VB. Why not just iterate through the loop from highest index backwards, and find it yourself?

Comment: Hi bob testing until I find my target,... what do you mean? I want the last occurrence so wouldn't I have to test to the END of the array?

Comment: yeah backwards might work jeremy. Then to keep track of my index I could ubound and neg increment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. I changed from Variant array to string, and made a FindLast function.

```
Sub test()

  Dim ary() As String
  Dim stg As String
  Dim i As Integer

  stg = "this,one,is,this,going,to,be,fun"
  ary = Split(stg, ",")

  MsgBox FindLast(ary, "this")

End Sub

Private Function FindLast(ary() As String, value As String) As Integer

  For i = UBound(ary) To 0 Step -1
    If ary(i) = value Then
        FindLast = i
        Exit For
    End If
  Next

End Function
```

Comment: Just built almost the same thing on my end. Although I added a way to handle not found.

Comment: @JohnsonJason way to go!

Comment: Thanks for the help